# Simple error yet very annoying appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I've basically got this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Which is this line

```
    s.append(

    );
} <-- this is the syntax error
```

Here's the full jQuery in which I'm trying to perform

```
var s = $('<select id="addressList" class="txt" style="width:150px;letter-spacing: 0px;"/><input type="button" class="submit" id="chooseAddress" value="Submit"><br/><br/>');
var items = [];
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    if(val.address != undefined) {
        var textString = value.address;
        var valueVar = value.address;
        s.append(
            $('<option data-town="' + value.town + '" data-street="' + value.street + '" data-town="' + value.town + '" data-number="' + value.number + '"></option>').val(valueVar).html(textString);
        );
    }
});
```

I'm sorry for posting such basic, but It's literally been mind boggling me for how long

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the `;` after the `option` is created:

```
s.append(
    $('<option data-town="' + value.town + '" data-street="' + value.street + '" data-town="' + value.town + '" data-number="' + value.number + '"></option>').val(valueVar).html(textString) // <- no ; here
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove semicolon

```
html(textString);
```